# jQuery: How do I trigger .slideToggle() on links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

How do I perform a jQuery 'slidetoggle' effect using a hyperlink, instead of an input button, as the action item?

At the jQuery reference [page](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideToggle#speedcallback)

It only gives an example of using a form input button.

I would like to have instead of a button, a hyperlink to be the toggle clickable action.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#anch").click(function () {
      $("#para1").slideToggle("slow");
    });



<a id='anch'>Toggle</a>
  <p id='para1'>
    This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You
    should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
    your life.  Congratulations!
  </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a link like so:

```
<a id="toggleLink" href="#">CLICK ME!</a>
```

Just use the following function to slideToggle your div

```
 $("#toggleLink").click(function () {
      $("#myDiv").slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

Comment: Right, but the link has a URL, so if it's clicked I have to preventDefault to initiate the slideToggle. I need the link to be clickable to go to the page, but also open the nest UL which has a hidden submenu. Doing a hover() make its jumpy

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, if your hyperlink has an `href` attribute (which it should, so it will be displayed as a link), you may want to neutralize it by returning `false` on your event handler (if you don't, the page will scroll up when you click on the link):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('p').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Other than that, there shouldn't be any difference between a button and an hyperlink. While you're reading the documentation, you'd be wise to start with [jQuery's Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).